# react/redux don't return dispatch

Tags: redux, react-redux

I really don't know why this action doesn't work. The action stops before returning dispatch function(only 'working' is logged)

```
   export function authAdmin({nickname, password}){ 
      console.log('working');
    return function(dispatch){
      console.log('still working');
    axios.post(`${URL}/admin`, {nickname, password})
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            dispatch({type: AUTH_ADMIN});
            browserHistory.push('/');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }); 
      }
    }
```

But nearly identical action is working with no problems. Am i missing something obvious ?

```
     export function getPosts(page){
     return function(dispatch){
      dispatch({ type: IS_FETCHING });
      axios.get(`${URL}/home?page=${page}`)
          .then(response => {
            dispatch ({
            type: FETCH_POSTS,
            payload: response.data        
          })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({ type: ERROR_FETCHING });
          });
    }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling each action creator?  My guess is that `getPosts()` is being dispatched correctly, while `authAdmin()` is not actually being dispatched (just executed separately).

Comment: Yes that was it :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

This usually happens when you call the thunk function by itself, meaning that the inner function does not get passed to `dispatch()`:

```
import {someThunkActionCreator} from "./actions";

// Wrong - just returns the inner function, but never runs it
someThunkActionCreator(); 

// Right - passes the inner function to dispatch, which runs it
dispatch(someThunkActionCreator())

// Right - creates a bound-up version which auto-dispatches
const boundThunk = bindActionCreators(someThunkActionCreator, dispatch); 
boundThunk();
```